# Command Line Argument as java File

Tags: java

I am trying to pass a java file as command line arg in Eclipse. But, each and every time , it's throwing `FileNotFoundException` and showing Error - Product.java(The System cannot find the file specified). I have this Product file in same package as my main java file.
    One more point to mention, I am using `FileReader`. `BufferedReader` in my program to read that file. Is there anything that I am missing?

package com.assign6.keyword.count;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CountKeywords {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] accessifiers = {"public", "protected", "private"};

        // Put each keyword in map with key
        Map<String, Integer> theKeyWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for( String str : accessifiers ){
            theKeyWordCount.put(str, 0);
            // Where str is key and 0 is value of Map
        }

        FileReader fr;
        BufferedReader br;
        File file = new File(args[0]);

        System.out.println(file);
        // Open and read the file

        try {

            fr = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String line;

            while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ){

                if( line.length() != 0 ){

                    if( theKeyWordCount.containsKey(line) ){

                        theKeyWordCount.put(line, theKeyWordCount.get(line)+1 );
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // File not found
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Not able to read line
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(theKeyWordCount);

    }// end main method

}
```

Comment: Have a look at the working directory where your code is running, and check whether the file has been copied there... currently we don't really have enough context to help you. (We don't know how your code is running, or what it looks like, or why you're trying to load a source file in the first place...)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's always a better idea to post relevant code, so that we can understand what actually went wrong. In your particular case, the command you used will also be valuable.

Comment: could you give an example of the code and/or the arguments you pass on?
It's probabily because you typed the path of your file wrong.
try using \\ instead of \ as directoryseparator

Answer (score 1):

> I have this Product file in same package as my main java file.

That's not really relevant. Instead, you want `Product.java` to be in the current working directory when you *run* the program. (For example, if you run your program as `java -jar path/to/program.jar`, then you need `Product.java` to be in the folder that contains `path`.)

Comment: @user2602915: Don't put your code in a comment - edit your question. At the moment there really isn't much we can help you with...

Comment: @user2602915: All I can say, is please re-read my answer. That's about all the help I can offer. :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you try to execute the following code with assumption that your *CountKeywords* is located in `/home/username/javaProject` folder :

```
package com.assign6.keyword.count

public class CurrentDirectoryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Working Directory = "
         + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
}
```

you should get:

```
Working Directory = /home/username/javaProject
```

It means that Java looks for your file inside `javaProject` and not inside

```
/home/username/javaProject/com/assign6/keyword/count
```

To get your class working you need:

- to move the file to the `/home/username/javaProject` folder

or

- specify the path related to `javaProject`. In your case it means `com/assign6/keyword/count/Product.java`

Comment: Or specify the fully qualified path